# Ionic build issue after adding Localnotification plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

In my Ionic application after installing Cordova local notification plugin, there are some android build Issue. [image: See error screenshot]

To resolve this I have installed Android support library and add it in my application but still problem faced. If anyone have any idea please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue, sorted it by running Android SDK Manager and installing the latest Android Support Library, Android Support Repository, Google Play Services and Google Repository (neither Google add-in was originally installed).

[image: Add stuff with SDK Manager]

Comment: Thanks man, After installing all 4 packages, build is working.